# Rotation in unity

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I am trying to rotate a game object using the lerp command, however I am getting the following error:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `float' to`
>   UnityEngine.Quaternion'

This is the code I am using

```
box.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(NewAngle, Vector3.right);
boxAngle = box.rotation.x;
targetAngle = 90.0f;
NewAngle = Mathf.Lerp(boxAngle, targetAngle, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A quarternion is not a rotation. Use a vector3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `box` is an `Transform`, this should work, but if you're rotating only on one axis it will be much easier to use

```
box.eulerAngles=new Vector3(NewAngle, 0f, 0f);
```

Also, there other two potential issues:

1. lerping after it's set - you've got a potential one frame lag
2. [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) or modulo 360 problems (think how will 350 lerp to 90 - it will go the long way around)

How about:

```
Quaternion targetAngle=Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0f, 0f);
box.rotation=Quaternion.Lerp(box.rotation, targetAngle, Time.deltaTime*smooth);
```